# What is the relation between address lines and memory?

Tags: memory, memory-address

These are my assignments:

> Write a program to find the number of address lines in an `n` Kbytes of memory. Assume that `n` is always to the power of 2.

**Sample input:** 2

**Sample output:** 11

I don't need specific coding help, but I don't know the relation between address lines and memory.

Comment: Don't show your homework assignment, show some code you wrote when trying to do your home work!

Comment: @sqlab I think this question is ok without code. Whether the question itself is OT, that's another matter. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To express in very easy terms, without any bus-multiplexing, the number of bits required to address a memory is the number of *lines* (address or data) required to access that memory.

Quoting from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_bus) article,

> a system with a 32-bit address bus can address 2<sup>32</sup> (4,294,967,296) memory locations.

for a simple example, consider this, you have 3 address lines (`A`, `B`, `C`), so the values which can be formed using 3 bits are

```
A B C
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Total 8 values. So using `ABC`, you can access any of those eight values, i.e., you can *reach* any of those memory addresses.

So, **TL;DR**, the simple relationship is, with `n` number of *lines*, we can represent 2<sup>n</sup> number of addresses.

Answer (score 1):

An address line usually refers to a physical connection between a CPU/chipset and memory. They specify which address to access in the memory. So the task is to find out how many bits are required to pass the input number as an address.

In your example, the input is 2 kilobytes = 2048 = 2^11, hence the answer 11. If your input is 64 kilobytes, the answer is 16 (65536 = 2^16).